# printing the graph using networkx, shows error 'Input is not a correct numpy matrix or array'

Tags: networkx

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt

A=np.array([[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0]])
G = nx.DiGraph(A)
```

---

when iam trying to print graph of above matrix it shows error

```
pos=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1]]
nx.draw(G,pos)
plt.savefig("2trial.png",format="PNG")
```

Comment: You have an empty element in your array `,,`

Comment: after correcting it also it shows error

Comment: I think you need to understand how to correctly construct a Graph in NetworkX, I see no support to pass an array of lists containing 4 elements, normally one passes an array of pairs or 2-element sequences. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: actually iam trying to print the graph of matrix(which is not a square matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Networkx has a [special function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_matrix.html?highlight=from_numpy_matrix#networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_matrix) to construct a graph from numpy adjacency matrix:

`G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)`

However, an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) must be square:

> In graph theory and computer science, an adjacency matrix is a square matrix used to represent a finite graph. The elements of the matrix indicate whether pairs of vertices are adjacent or not in the graph.

So you can't create a graph with your matrix because it is not an adjacency matrix. You should convert it to a 5x5 matrix and then send to `nx.from_numpy_matrix` function:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

A=np.array([[0,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0,1]])
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
pos=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1]]
nx.draw(G,pos)
```

[image]